# Double backslash into path

Tags: node.js, multer

I have using this the tuttorial of Academind how to load image using multer into node JavaScript rest service.
About path destination folder I use this code:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function(req, file, cb) {
cb(null, './uploads/');
},
filename: function(req, file, cb) {
cb(null, file.originalname);
}
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
// reject a file
if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
cb(null, true);
} else {
cb(null, false);
}
};

const upload = multer({
storage: storage,
limits: {
fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
},
fileFilter: fileFilter
});
```

But the path generated have double backslash that show as one backslash:
uploads\2018-09-16T13-02-45.535Z1536685465dummy4.jpg
How I can replace destination path with slash?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, and since i didn't find anything i did this as a work around

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `${new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-')}${file.originalname.split(" ").join("_")}`);
    }
});

const user= new User({
            _id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            name : req.body.name,
            image: req.file.destination + req.file.filename, 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check on the frontend to find and replace that backslash with normal `/` and then it will work.

here some example:
`const image =  resData.post.imageUrl.slice(0,6) + '/' + resData.post.imageUrl.slice(7)`